# How to display JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

So i have written this code to get a json from API.AI. i want to know how to echo out the decoded JSON file on this form. Currently the decoded JSON is being saved in a new file JSON.php, but instead of saving i want to know how to view it?

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
file_put_contents("JSON.php", print_r($data, true));
```

Comment: If you have written this code, you probably have an idea of what `print_r()` does...

Comment: yeah i know what it does. but i tried print_r ($data); but it doesnt work

Comment: `var_dump($data)`

Answer (score 0):

As comments state you can use var_dump to view the rough data but if you actually wanna use it for something you might wanna loop over the object and extracte properties.

like so:

```
foreach($data as $theData)
{
 echo $theData->property;
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

do like this:-

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

$request = json_decode($postdata);

print_r($request);

or you can do :-  $request->indexname

Comment: Hi, but its not printing out the array :(

Comment: are you running this on local?